# dimensionResource crashes with "NotFoundException: Resource ID type #0x4 is not valid"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here I have stuck with `dimensionResource(id)`. I don't know why it is not working but other `stringResource(id)`, `colorResource(id)` and `painterResource(id)` are working fine.

Here are associated files.

**1)Ui Composable (DimenErrorTest.kt)**

```
package com.kot.androidkotapp.ui.common
import android.content.res.Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO
import android.content.res.Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
import androidx.compose.foundation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import com.kot.androidkotapp.R
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.kot.androidkotapp.CartItem
import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
import com.kot.androidkotapp.summaryItems
import com.kot.androidkotapp.ui.theme.*

@Composable
fun DimenErrorTest(
) {

//Here, error occured
    val buttonModifier = Modifier
        .padding(end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.p1))

//while String resources works 
    val buttonText:String = stringResource(id = R.string.click_me)).toString()

    //Buttons
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = buttonModifier,
            onClick = {}

        ) {
            Text(buttonText)
        }

    }
}
```

**2.) Project Level Gradle File**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        hilt_version = '2.41'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def gradle = '7.0.2'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle"

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**3.) App Level Gradle File**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kot.androidkotapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '...'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //default dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'

    //hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.41'

    //compose viewmodel
    def viewmodel_ktx = "2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$viewmodel_ktx"

    //appcompat
    def app_compact = "1.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$app_compact"

    //compose constraint
    def compose_constraint = "1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:$compose_constraint"

    //navigation version
    def nav_version = "2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // For instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation  "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // For local unit tests
    testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    //testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

}

//telling hilt kapt to correct error types
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

**4.) Dimens in Resources**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="p1">5</dimen>
    <dimen name="p2">10</dimen>
    <dimen name="p3">15</dimen>
    <dimen name="p4">20</dimen>
</resources>
```

**5.) Strings in Resources**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="click_me">Click Me</string>
</resources>
```

**6.) Error**

```
2022-04-05 12:35:08.428 28620-28620/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kot.androidkotapp, PID: 28620
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0601af type #0x4 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimension(Resources.java:758)
        at androidx.compose.ui.res.PrimitiveResources_androidKt.dimensionResource(PrimitiveResources.android.kt:79)
        at com.kot.androidkotapp.ui.common.KotSummaryKt.KotSummary(KotSummary.kt:49)
        at com.kot.androidkotapp.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1$1$1$1$1$invoke$$inlined$itemsIndexed$default$2.invoke(LazyDsl.kt:274)
        at com.kot.androidkotapp.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1$1$1$1$1$invoke$$inlined$itemsIndexed$default$2.invoke(LazyDsl.kt:120)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListScopeImpl$items$1$1.invoke(LazyListScopeImpl.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListScopeImpl$items$1$1.invoke(LazyListScopeImpl.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$content$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$content$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3337)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2582)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2522)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:478)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:748)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2987)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:269)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:154)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:55)
2022-04-05 12:35:08.430 28620-28620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1175)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:235)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose$ui_release(SubcomposeLayout.kt:224)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:490)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPlaceablesProvider.getAndMeasure-0kLqBqw(LazyMeasurePolicy.kt:58)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure-oA9-DU0(LazyMeasuredItemProvider.kt:45)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-wroFCeY(LazyListMeasure.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.measure-3p2s80s(LazyList.kt:259)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:44)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:355)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:306)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:115)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:306)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:878)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:658)
2022-04-05 12:35:08.432 28620-28620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1798)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1317)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:168)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:201)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:703)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24851)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:302)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:289)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6908)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:221)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6908)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6908)
2022-04-05 12:35:08.432 28620-28620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.measureChildWithMargins(DecorView.java:3032)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:221)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:863)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24851)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2321)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7998)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1111)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:927)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:856)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1096)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7880)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

Comment: Add this implementation and try implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.1'

Comment: implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
$compose_version = 1.1.1 it is already there but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension), `dimen` value should be followed by a unit of measure. For example `dp`:

```xml
<dimen name="p1">5dp</dimen>
```